# How to create generic method to update multiple columns in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have this generic method to update one column

```scala
def updateColumn[V](id: Int, 
    column: Table[UserRow] => Rep[V], 
    value:  V)(implicit shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, Rep[V], V, _]) =
    userTableQuery.filter(user => user.id  === id).map(column).update(value))
```

So, I can use it like this

```scala
updateColumn(1, user => user.firstName, "FirstName")
```

I would like to use it for multiple columns

```scala
updateColumn(1, user => (user.firstName, user.lastName), ("FirstName", "LastName"))
```

But It has a compile error

```
No matching Shape found
Required level: slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api.FlatShapeLevel
Source type: slick.lifted.Rep[(String, String)]
```

Is it possible to create such method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is possible

```scala
def update[F, G, K](id: Int, 
  columns: Table[UserRow] => F, 
  value: K)(implicit shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, F, K, G]) =
    userTableQuery.filter(user => user.id  === id).map(columns).update(value)
```